# Magento2 change to production mode

Tags: magento2, compiler, hosting, ssh, centos

i want to change from developer to production, but i can't because i get an error that exec function is disabled and my host will not enable it.

What are the actions taking place when you type

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Can I do it step by step with these commands?

- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- Enable production mode through .htaccess

Is there anything else i have to do in order to have the same result?

Comment: are u enable to do  magento  `bin/magento ` .

Comment: If on your server php-cli working the using php cli you can do. first ensure that you can run php -cli.Other wish cannot be possible to changes  model. If php cli is working the using `
 - Goto `app/etc/` and open `env.php`
 - and change current application mode by **`MAGE_MODE' => 'default'`**
   to **`MAGE_MODE' => 'production'`` then run `:static-content:deploy` and di compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can follow below steps

- go to `app/etc/env.php` file
- Set `MAGE_MODE' => 'production'`
- Run below commands

  ```
  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
  bin/magento setup:di:compile
  ```